# Same word can only be used once in a string

Tags: php

I have a simple message function on my site, today i started working on making it possible to sent to multiple users, this is how far I've come:

works good so far, but i just realized you chould just enter the same username several times

so how can i restrict to occurance of same word only once? is there a function for this? googling 'php same word only once' and similiar i dont find much, but my english is not excellent

```
$recipients = 'bob;randomhero;wambamtymam;bill'; // exempel

$recipients_exploded = explode(';', $recipients);
foreach ($recipients_exploded as $recipient) {

    if (empty($recipients)) {
        $error = 'vänligen ange åtminstone en mottagare';
    }

    else if (count($recipients_exploded) > 10) {
        $error = 'du kan endast skicka till 10 stycken användare i ett och samma svep';
    }

    else if (!usernameExist($recipient)) {
        $error = 'det finns ingen användare vid namn '.htmlspecialchars($recipient).'.';
    }
```

Comment: `$recipients_exploded = array_unique(array_filter(explode(';', $recipients)));`

Comment: that was fast, thank you!!

Comment: but now my error checks dont work, it dont recognize as empty even if it is empty. why?

Comment: That's what `array_filter()` does.... never simply copy/paste any answer from SO blindly.... always look at the functions that are used and understand how it works.... this site is about teaching you (or at least helping you learn) not about writing code for you

Comment: you're right, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) it  will give you unique values.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
$recipients_array= explode(';', $recipients);
$unique_recipients_array = array_unique($recipients_array);
```

### Explanation

Your username entries are separated by `;` character. So first, you have to separate each usernames using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method and form an array.

Now, php has a function called [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). It will accept an array as input and return unique elements as an array. So `$unique_recipients_array` will contain only unique entries